# .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) crashes Xcode preview

Tags: xcode, debugging, swiftui

I am consistently coming across this issue whenever I use `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)`. Is there a problematic use of this method, or is there something incorrect about my code ?

How to reproduce error:

In the preview, hit the `"list.bullet.rectangle.fill"` and dismiss the dialog. Do it a second time and now Xcode crashes the Preview.

**Xcode Version 14.2 (14C18)**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct PDFTableContentsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("PDF Table Contents View")
        .bold()
        .underline()
    }
}

struct PDFContentView: View {
    @State private var showContents: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
        }
        .navigationTitle("PDF Title")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button {
                    showContents.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "list.bullet.rectangle.fill")
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showContents) {
            PDFTableContentsView()
        }
    }
}

struct PDFContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            PDFContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: on Xcode 14.1 it just crashes the preview, not the Xcode itself.
Also, no crash on the actual app. Also, just crash on the second touch of the botton

Comment: Thank you for testing. I’ll clarify the title.